# Searching for list of terms using Google in order to build a bag-of-words for a particular category

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning, multi-class, bag-of-words

I am having a hard time understanding the process of building a bag-of-words. This will be a multiclass classification supervised machine learning problem wherein a webpage or a piece of text is assigned to one category from multiple pre-defined categories. Now the method that I am familiar with when building a bag of words for a specific category (for example, 'Math') is to collect a lot of webpages that are related to Math. From there, I would perform some data processing (such as remove stop words and performing TF-IDF) to obtain the bag-of-words for the category 'Math'.

Question: Another method that I am thinking of is to instead search in google for something like 'List of terms related to Math' to build my bag-of-words. I would like to ask if this is method is okay?

Another question: In the context of this question, does bag-of-words and corpus mean the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the second question first, they are not. A corpus is simply a set of documents. The [bag of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) assumption means, loosely, that the order of words in a document doesn't matter. It's applied in many language models, just about any that disregards grammar but maintains a count of words used.

To your primary question, I think you're interested in deriving predictive features for a particular class, and asking whether you can do that manually. (This seems to be how you're using the term "bag of words.") In principle sure, you could come up with a list of terms related to math or neurobiology and use those as features in a learning algorithm.

But there are methods like [supervised topic models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.0783.pdf) to do that for you, though the only [implementation](https://github.com/blei-lab) I'm aware of is an academic one written in C++. This would be a more principled way of deriving what you're interested in, and would save you a thousand Google searches.

Comment: Just to clarify. So in my case a corpus would be a set of webpages? Thank you for the suggestion, would definitely look at it. Looking at the pdf you gave, I've seen LDA in scikit-learn before.

Comment: Yep, that's right re corpus. FYI, LDA and *supervised* LDA are different models. sLDA adds a formal model of classification to LDA, which has no notion of category within the corpus. LDA is long-standing (2003) and pretty well-established among ML software packages; I haven't seen sLDA in the wild yet. One approach is to use LDA on your corpus, then use its derived topics as input to a classifier.

Comment: Alright thanks for the information. Another question that is confusing to me. When gathering my corpus/web pages for category 'Math', do I label it 'Math' using my own intuition or is there some formal way of verifying that is indeed 'Math'? This would be prior to dividing it into train and test set.

Comment: Application-specific, but expert hand-labelling is about the only method I'm aware of for the task you describe.

Comment: By hand-labelling, do you mean manually labelling them?

Comment: That is correct.